# change textview font type at design time in android

Tags: android

I am new android developer , I am design such type of application ,In my application i want to see to actual look of textview at **design time when change the different font in eclipse ** .

Here ,I am giving one example .

[image]

Please help me is there any way to possible to see different font style at design time ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [TTF font](http://www.webpagepublicity.com/free-fonts.html) for this.You need to download and put this in assets folder and then use Typeface for this.You'll have to manage at runtime according to the project requirement.

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Alan Den.ttf");
 tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Hope this will work,for any query let me know.Good luck

Comment: i want change at design time.

Comment: You cannot because there is not more option there only sens,serif,normal and monospace.more more look http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:typeface